# backbone make collection searches case insenitive

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am searching a backbone collection like this,

```
search: function( filterValue ) {

    var filterThroughValue = function(data) {

        return _.some(_.values(data.toJSON()), function(value) {
            if(value != undefined) {
                value = (!isNaN(value) ? value.toString() : value);

                return value.indexOf(filterValue) >= 0;
            }
        });
    };

    return App.Collections.filterCollection = this.filter(filterThroughValue);
}
```

The search parameters come from an text input, I am wanting to return results regardless or letter casing is this possible? Can I get the params and what is being searched to lowercase?

Comment: "Can I get the params and what is being searched to lowercase" - yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the value you are testing and your search term to lower case:

```
// At the start of `search`
filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();

// In your `some` predicate:
return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) >= 0;
```

As an aside, it would be cleaner to implement most of the logic in your Model class:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  matches: function(term) {
    var lowerCaseTerm = term.toLowerCase();
    return this.values().some(function(value) {
      if(!value) return false;
      return value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseTerm) >= 0;
    })
  }
})

MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  search: function(term) {
    return this.filter(function(model) {
      return model.matches(term) 
    })
  }
})
```